# Enable password change using updatePassword and reauthenticate (Firebase+Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, change-password

I want to allow password change on the site I am building. I used information from stackoverflow and from what I saw on the Internet, before using the `updatePassword` function it is recommended to `reauthenticate` ,to verify identification of the user.
The following function did not work for me, do you have any idea why?

```
  auth_state: any = null;

  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.firebaseAuth.auth_state.subscribe((auth =>{
      this.auth_state= auth;
    }))
  }
```

```
  changePassword(new_password) {
    var credentials =  this.auth_state.prototype.reauthenticateWithCredential.EmailAuthProvider.credential("email@example.com", "oldPassword");
    this.auth_state.prototype.reauthenticate(credentials)
      .then(() => {
        this.auth_state.prototype.updatePassword(new_password)
          .then(() => {
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

the erorr I got was:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reauthenticateWithCredential' of undefined
```